# Manually trigger scheduled or trigger function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way to manually trigger a scheduled function and/or a Firestore trigger function? I have two scenarios I need to solve:

1. A cloud function that is listening to a Firestore document (onCreate) didn't fire - it failed on 3 of about 1,000 invocations, so I need to manually trigger it for these 3 documents. Is this possible (to manually trigger this function)?
2. I have a scheduled function that runs hourly, but threw an error b/c of a map in the Firestore document when the code expected an array. Any way I can manually run the scheduled function once rather than waiting an hour before it runs again?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

-- firebase console
-- functions
-- "..." at right side of cron job
-- "view in cloud scheduler"
-- "run now" at right side of function

Answer (score 2):

You can run a firestore scheduled function via the FirebaseTools and running it locally. Starting the shell command eg `npm run build && firebase functions:shell` will allow you to invoke a Scheduled Function eg:

```
export const parseGarminHealthAPIActivityQueue = functions.region('europe-west2').runWith({
  timeoutSeconds: TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS,
  memory: MEMORY
}).pubsub.schedule('every 10 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {
  await parseQueueItems(ServiceNames.GarminHealthAPI);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

It's not possible to manually trigger a function from the Firebase console.  Your best bet is to use the methods shown in the [Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/direct), which involve using gcloud's call command or the Cloud console's Testing tab.  Neither of these are very easy, as you will have to construct the JSON payload to the function manually.

If I may make a suggestion - if your functions are failing due to errors, you should consider enabling retry on your functions, and making sure that your functions only generate errors for situations that should be retried.  Depending on manual invocation in the event of a failure will not scale very well - errors should be handled by code as much as possible.

Comment: @I'mJoeToo I may be misunderstanding the question but if you're using [Cloud Firestore triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore), as mentioned in the question, why can't the Cloud Function observe a different specific document in Firestore for changes, and when a property is changed from false to true (for example) have it trigger the cloud function - that would be *manually triggering* the function, no? You could certainly do that from the console or from your app.

Comment: For the Firestore triggers, yes - I can write a script to copy a doc, delete it, and re-add it to retrigger. I was hoping there was some other way to retry. For scheduled, I found (thanks to your link) a "Run Now" button in the console I can use.